# Create footer for subsection in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, ios9

I am trying to have a subsection in an ios tableView.

Here is the code I am using to create subsection.

```
var sections = [[
                    ["p", "q", "r"],
                    ["p1", "q1", "r1"]
                ],
                [
                    ["a", "b"]
                ]]
var sectionHeaders = [["P", "P1"], ["A"]]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:     Int) -> Int {
    let sectionItems = self.sections[section]
    var numberOfRows = sectionItems.count // For second level section headers

    for rowItems in sectionItems {
        numberOfRows += rowItems.count // For actual table rows
    }
    return numberOfRows
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sectionItems = self.sections[indexPath.section]
    let sectionHeader = self.sectionHeaders[indexPath.section]
    let itemAndSubsectionIndex = self.computeItemAndSubsectionIndexForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let subsectionIndex = itemAndSubsectionIndex.section
    let itemIndex = itemAndSubsectionIndex.row

    if (itemIndex < 0) {
        // Section header
    } else {
        // Row Item
    }
}

func computeItemAndSubsectionIndexForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {
    var sectionItems = self.sections[indexPath.section]
    var itemIndex = indexPath.row
    var subsectionIndex = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < sectionItems.count; ++i) {
        // First row for each section item is header
        --itemIndex
        // Check if the item index is within this subsection's items
        let subsectionItems = sectionItems[i]
        if (itemIndex < subsectionItems.count) {
            subsectionIndex = i
            break
        } else {
            itemIndex -= subsectionItems.count
        }
    }
    return NSIndexPath(forRow: itemIndex, inSection: subsectionIndex)
}
```

This code is working fine and I am able to create headers for each subsection. But the problem is how to create a footer for that subsection. As The second level header is a row, so footer should also be a row, but how to find out that it is a footer row.

Any help will be appreciated.

Hope you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a different way to do headers and footers in a UITableView where you don't treat them like regular rows. Have at look into these UITableViewDelegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

If you just want text for the headers and footers, try the UITableViewDataSource delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String?
```

Comment: I am trying to implement subsections...I have viewforheader and viewforfooter implemented for outer header and footer. I want second level header and footer. I am able to implement second level header, i am trying to implement second level footer